# Wordpress - I need to add date AFTER the title

Tags: date, text

I have some code and I'm trying to add a line-break, than the date. In the current code it shows the date than the title on the same line.

Can someone help?

```
            <div class="post-title">
            <?php the_title('<div class="entry-title title-h4"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark"'.(!empty($item_colors['post_title_color']) ? ' style="color: '.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_color']).(!empty($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']) ? ' onmouseenter="jQuery(this).data(\'color\', this.style.color);this.style.color=\''.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']).'\';" onmouseleave="this.style.color=jQuery(this).data(\'color\');"' : '').'"' : '').'>'.(!$params['hide_date'] ? get_the_date('d M').': ' : '').'<span class="light">', '</span></a></div>'); ?>
        </div>
```

All help is appreciated! The date and text line is at the end of the code block.

Edit: I have managed to reverse the data successfully, but the date is no longer styled properly and doesn't follow the correct style. How do I move the date and keep it styled? Here's the code I ended up with:

```
            <div class="post-title">
            <?php the_title('<div class="entry-title title-h4"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark"'.(!empty($item_colors['post_title_color']) ? ' style="color: '.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_color']).(!empty($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']) ? ' onmouseenter="jQuery(this).data(\'color\', this.style.color);this.style.color=\''.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']).'\';" onmouseleave="this.style.color=jQuery(this).data(\'color\');"' : '').'"' : '').'>'. '<span class="light">', '</span></a></div>'.(!$params['hide_date'] ? get_the_date('d M').': ' : '')); ?>
        </div>
```

Edit 2:

I've gotten a little further. I successfully placed the date at the end of the text and kept it styled. But I'd like to have it under the title, I want to add a line-break. Anyone? Here's the code I ended up with:

```
            <div class="post-title">
            <?php the_title('<div class="entry-title title-h4"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark"'.(!empty($item_colors['post_title_color']) ? ' style="color: '.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_color']).(!empty($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']) ? ' onmouseenter="jQuery(this).data(\'color\', this.style.color);this.style.color=\''.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']).'\';" onmouseleave="this.style.color=jQuery(this).data(\'color\');"' : '').'"' : '').'>'. '<span class="light">', '</span>'.(!$params['hide_date'] ? get_the_date('d M').'  ' : '').'</a></div>'); ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it all out by myself. Figured I'd post the answer here in-case someone needed this someday.

```
<div class="post-title">
            <?php the_title('<div class="entry-title title-h4"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark"'.(!empty($item_colors['post_title_color']) ? ' style="color: '.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_color']).(!empty($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']) ? ' onmouseenter="jQuery(this).data(\'color\', this.style.color);this.style.color=\''.esc_attr($item_colors['post_title_hover_color']).'\';" onmouseleave="this.style.color=jQuery(this).data(\'color\');"' : '').'"' : '').'>'.     '<span class="light">', '</span>'.'<br>'.(!$params['hide_date'] ? get_the_date('d M').' ' : '').'</a></div>'); ?>
        </div>
```